Sending to multiple recipients MuleSoft Email SMTP
I have been trying to send to multiple recipients but to no avail.
Currently I define a transform to split then join the recipient string then pass it to the email connector, but it fails saying
Error while sending email: Error while creating email1@domain.com,email2@domain.com InternetAddress
The original transform is defined as below:
if((emailString as String) contains "," )
        (emailString as String) splitBy "," joinBy ","
    else if(emailString != "" and emailString != null)
        [emailString]
    else
        null

I am wondering if there is a bug or special case I have not seen while checking the documentation.

You are splitting the string containing emails addresses but then you are joining the resulting items back into a string. Just pass the resulting array to the connector. You probably don't need the other cases. splitBy() already returns a single element if the split character is not found and returns null if the input is null.
Example:
<email:send toAddresses="#[vars.emailString splitBy(&quot;,&quot;)]" ... >

Reference: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=001114454&type=1

So the connector takes a java array of Strings? I wish it was clearer on the documents about accessing this. Thanks for the pointer I will apply this pattern.

The documentation of the send operation actually says To Addresses is an
Array of String.

@EF You already were passing an array of string when the emailString didn't have ,
